# Typo on passport before applying US visa

Tags: visas, air-travel, usa, passports, international-travel

My in-laws are planning to apply for United States tourist visa (B). While applying for a passport, they made a typo and as a result, my mother-in-law's first name became "Mrs ABC". Based on my experience, I believe it will create a lot of problems when applying for US visas, buying air tickets, etc.

Should they use the wrong/typo first name when applying for visa or they should fix it before applying US visa to avoid further issues ?

Comment: Change/Update the passport with correct name. It is not advisable to keep an incorrect name on the passport.

Comment: Do not wait. Have the passport corrected immediately. This is not something you should delay.

Comment: You mean THE PASSPORT !!!!!!!!!!!! (not the visa) has a typo!??  That's - incredible.  Completely forget about the trip until it is fixed.

Comment: Get it fixed, and get fast priority service, and it's the issuing authorites screw up so they should pay for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to correct the passport as soon as possible. Don't ever travel with a passport that has a typo. You would risk one of the followings :

- end up in jail (worse case)
- end up in a retention center
- be denied country entry at the airport until this is sorted out
- have to go back to your country of origin without any delay
- pay a fine

So don't try, you would run into problems and lose money if not more...

Answer (score 3):

They must have their passports corrected ***immediately***, and stay away from foreign authorities until it's done. The US, in particular, is very quick to draw the conclusion that an applicant is committing fraud in some way, and if they do, you can ***forget ever setting foot there in your life***